# How to reduce residual error?

Tags: r, time-series, spectral-analysis

I have a time series as following. It has an upward trend and weak sesonality (found in ACF). I tried spectral analysis, but the residual error kept staying over 600, which is not small enough for a prediction. Any advice? Thx!

```
ts <- c(1530.040 3527.839 3327.613 3613.749 2971.990 3747.925 3352.686 5203.718 4550.774 3497.677 2719.688 2618.564 1378.669 3743.931 5094.959 3998.374 3649.445 3709.277 4078.814 6663.439 5774.322 4881.767
4233.501 4824.077 3207.395 6078.317 5398.443 3541.734 2852.284 3253.765 4716.344 5239.078 5267.733 4072.201 3796.414 4309.636 3751.775 5954.923 5627.322 3862.649 3673.138 4551.715 5904.327 5712.579 6108.412 4706.165 5230.390 3756.871 3079.763 5934.894 5172.300 3194.798 3167.828 4333.597 4512.727 7609.356 7728.995 6024.994 4947.637 4491.105)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one way would be to use the `auto.arima` function in package [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf). Although this may not be the best model, it normally provides a reasonable result.

```
> #Change ts to x since ts is preserved as a function in package stats in R, so better not to use it!
> x<-c(1530.040,3527.839,3327.613,3613.749,2971.990,3747.925,3352.686,5203.718,4550.774,3497.677,2719.688,2618.564,1378.669,3743.931,5094.959,3998.374,3649.445,3709.277,4078.814,6663.439,5774.322,4881.767,4233.501,4824.077,3207.395,6078.317,5398.443,3541.734,2852.284,3253.765,4716.344,5239.078,5267.733,4072.201,3796.414,4309.636,3751.775,5954.923,5627.322,3862.649,3673.138,4551.715,5904.327,5712.579,6108.412,4706.165,5230.390,3756.871,3079.763,5934.894,5172.300,3194.798,3167.828,4333.597,4512.727,7609.356,7728.995,6024.994,4947.637,4491.105)
> library(forecast)
> fit.1=auto.arima(x,ic=c("bic"))
> summary(fit.1)
Series: x 
ARIMA(2,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1
      0.5180  -0.2824  -0.8828
s.e.  0.1366   0.1312   0.0700

sigma^2 estimated as 1155623:  log likelihood=-496.2
AIC=1000.4   AICc=1001.14   BIC=1008.71

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE     MAE      MPE     MAPE     MASE        ACF1
Training set 264.7344 1066.003 791.181 1.196378 18.82649 0.795997 -0.08522222
> 
> plot(1:length(x),x)
> points(1:length(x),fitted(fit.1),type="l",lwd=2)
```

It is using BIC criteria to find the model ARIMA(2,1,1). I have no idea what you mean by "residual error" as you didn't define it. But you can look at the Training set error measures in the summary and compare it with your model based on spectral analysis. All measures are defined and discussed in

Hyndman, R.J. and Koehler, A.B. (2006) "Another look at measures of forecast accuracy". International Journal of Forecasting, 22(4).

If you don't have access to this paper, then you can watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Lh1HlBUf8k)  by Prof. Hyndman. Specifically look at Min 18:32. :)

I included the original series and the fitted line in the following plot as well. As I said this may not be the best model, and if you decide to use it, you should check the model assumptions.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try another type of seasonality, not based on trigonometric functions. Like seasonal indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Is your data monthly? It would seem so. The patterns within the data when plotted and a significant ACF at lag 12 suggests seasonal modeling type approach like what germaniawerks suggested!  The "seasonal pulse" means a seasonal dummy was identified at hat point and on onward. There are a few outliers as well called "pulse".

Attached is the link to the full analysis https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t16k7d0jpi7q1u/example.zip

[image: Actual, Fit and Forecasts]

Y(T) =  4651.7
       +[X1(T)][(+  2293.8    )]                            :PULSE             5/  8    56
       +[X2(T)][(+  1364.8    )]                            :PULSE             2/  8    20
       +[X3(T)][(+  744.29    )]                            :SEASONAL PULSE    2/  9    21
       +[X4(T)][(+  1937.6    )]                            :SEASONAL PULSE    3/  2    26
       +[X5(T)][(+  1425.6    )]                            :SEASONAL PULSE    2/  3    15
       +[X6(T)][(+  800.56    )]                            :PULSE             4/  7    43
       +[X7(T)][(+  1336.5    )]                            :PULSE             5/  9    57
      +     [(1-  .554B** 1)(1-  .519B** 12)]**-1  [A(T)]

Comment: It seems you are fitting with many parameters. So it would be constructive if you can provide here the RMSE, AIC and BIC criteria to compare the models.

Comment: Yes, the model needs these parameters. These statistics are found in the stat.htm file in the zip file in the dropbox.com link.  These statistics can be misleading as minimizing the fit is not the goal.   The law of parsimony is what rules and random residuals that are random is what is what we are trying to satisfy.   The RMSE is 562.030.

Comment: I should add that initial identification via AIC and BIC statistics fail to completely "model" the patterns within the data. The real important statistic is the RMSE of the model errors. In terms of "over fitting" as you call it, all of the parameters are statistically significant and if they weren’t  then they wouldn't be in the model. If they weren’t included then significant anomalies would remain in the errors which would ruin the tests of randomness.

Comment: @Tom Reilly, thanks for your help. Could you explain the result a little bit? Coz I really don't understand the equation or how the equation was achieved. And I didn't find a detailed tutorial of autobox either.

Comment: An initial model was identified: (1,0,0)(1,0,0) which led to identifying some additive pulses. It appears that your model identification scheme was "confused" by the few pulses and 3 seasonal pulses that were in the data. If you wish ro discuss this in detail please contact me offline at my email address.